# Forbidden error when creating an OnlineMeeting using cURL in MS Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to create an onlineMeeting in CURL.
I granted all the permissions related to users and onlineMeetings for the App.(Both delegated and application). Also the user I use in the <my_user_id> is the global admin.

I first got the bearer token using client_credentails. Here was my request for it:

```
> curl -X POST -d
> 'grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=<my_client_id>&client_secret=<my_client_secret_value>&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default'
> https://login.microsoftonline.com/<my_tenant>/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

I received a bearer token for the above request.

Now I used this bearer token to create an onlineMeeting using this request:

```
curl -X POST 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<my_user_id>/onlineMeetings' -d '{"startDateTime":"2023-07-12T14:30:00", "endDateTime":"2023-07-12T16:30:00", "subject": "testMeeting"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer <bearer_token>"
```

This above request is giving me the below error:

```
{"error":{"code":"Forbidden","message":"","innerError":{"request-id":"<some_req_id>","date":"2023-02-02T15:37:46","client-request-id":"<some_id>"}}}
```

I thought this might be because of the bearer toke. But its not, as when I use the same bearer token in getting users, it is working fine. Like this below request:

```
curl -X GET 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer <bearer_token>
```

Comment: I read a thread where I have to manually login to Teams before using this API. I did that. But still seeing the same error. Also tried the same in Postman, and got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions) if you are using application permission for this API, tenant administrators must create an ***application access policy*** and grant it to a user to authorize the app configured in the policy to create online meetings on behalf of that user (with user ID specified in the request path).

Check details: [Configure application access to online meetings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/cloud-communication-online-meeting-application-access-policy)

Comment: The doc says I will need to use powershell to run the commands to set this access policy. Also it talks about Skype for business, which I am not sure why I need it. Is there a way to do this in the UI from Azure Portal?